# query has no destination for result data postgresql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

> *I am trying to fetch data from different db by using dblink through function but getting an error "query has no destination for result
>   data"
>
>   ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
>
>   HINT:  If
>   you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.*

This is my Query

```
-- ns_core_customer_group

  insert into 
  ns_core_customer_group(customer_group_id,
  customer_group_code,
  customer_group_name,
  advance_percent,
  discount_percent,
  sync_id,
  is_active,

  is_deleted,
  created_stamp,
  created_user,
  last_modified_stamp,
  last_modified_user)

  select customer_group_id,
  concat(local_store_id,'-',customer_group_id),
  customer_group_name,
  advance_percent,
  discount_percent,
  3,
  is_active,
  is_deleted,
  created_stamp,
  created_user,
  last_modified_stamp,
  last_modified_user

  from dblink('host=localhost user=postgres password=admin dbname=Fulfil_1.9.1','select customer_group_id,
  customer_group_code,
  customer_group_name,
  advance_percent,
  discount_percent,
  is_active,
  is_deleted,
  created_stamp,
  created_user,
  last_modified_stamp,
  last_modified_user from ns_core_customer_group')

  AS t1(customer_group_id integer,
  customer_group_code character varying(50),
  customer_group_name character varying(255),
  advance_percent numeric(5,2),
  discount_percent numeric(5,2),
  is_active integer,
  is_deleted integer,
  created_stamp timestamp without time zone,
  created_user integer,
  last_modified_stamp timestamp without time zone,
  last_modified_user integer);

  select setval('ns_core_customer_group_id_seq', (select coalesce(max(customer_group_id),0)+1 from ns_core_customer_group), false);
```

Comment: The question is not understandable, please add more details (where is the stored procedure??)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perform this :

```
setval(
  'ns_core_customer_group_id_seq', 
  (select coalesce(max(customer_group_id),0)+1 from ns_core_customer_group), 
  false
  );
```